# Убрать дубликаты и оставить уникальные значения в коллекции

Tags: java, kotlin

Как можно избавиться от дубликатов, сохранив при этом все уникальные записи?
Есть список состоящий из моделей:

```
data class State(val name:String, val yearId:Int)
```

Входные данные выглядят так (массив моделей):

1. `State("Первый", 3)`
2. `State("Первый", 1)`
3. `State("Первый", 1)`
4. `State("Первый", 2)`
5. `State("Второй", 3)`

На примере, необходимо сохранить элементы: 1,2,4,5.
! - Элементы с номером 2 и 3 идентичны, поэтому достаточно сохранить один из них.

Comment: Добавить hashCode, equals  и использовать Set - самый адекватный вариант

Answer (score 0, accepted):

так как data class уже реализует hashCode и equals, то можно сразу использовать [distinct](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/distinct.html)

```
val list = listOf(State(...), ...)
val newList = list.distinct()
```

Answer (score 2):

Тупая реализация выглядит так:

```
data class State(val name:String, val yearId:Int) {
    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return "$name+$yearId".hashCode()
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "State: name=$name, yearId=$yearId"
    }
}

fun main() {
    val statesList=ArrayList<State>()
    statesList.add(State("Первый", 3))
    statesList.add(State("Первый", 1))
    statesList.add(State("Первый", 1))
    statesList.add(State("Первый", 2))
    statesList.add(State("Второй", 3))
    val statesSet=HashSet<State>()
    for (state in statesList) {
        statesSet.add(state)
    }
    //тестируем
    for (state in statesSet) println(state.toString())
}
```